# How to tell JMockit not to override behavior of custom junit runners designed for integration testing

Tags: unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection, custom-component, jmockit

I have the following test method

```
@RunWith(MyCustomJUnit4Runner.class)
public class MyIntegrationTestWithACustomIntegrationRunner{
    @Test
    public void ensureStuffIsWiredCorrectly(Dependency myDependency){

    }
}
```

This method is ran with a custom runner that injects the wired dependency.

JMockit also injects mocks in this scenario.

Normally I would want the jmockit behaviors, however this case I need the platform injected item rather than the mocked version.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Please feel free to comment on how I can clarify the obviously ambiguous question.

pom entries:

```
<dependencies>

<!-- CUSTOM INTEGRATION RUNNER -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.clinkworks</groupId>
        <artifactId>neptical</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>[4.0,5.0)</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to upgrade JMockit to version 1.7 or newer:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency
```